# Confused by JavaFX ListChangeListener.Change

Tags: javafx-2

I'm confused by the terminology in ListChangeListener.Change in JavaFX.  I had an observable list and called `set(index,newValue)` on the list.

On the resulting change I observed the following change attributes:

```
wasRemoved() == true
wasReplaced() == false
wasUpdated() == false
```

Thankfully, getAddedSublist() contained the new value but I would have expected wasReplaced or wasUpdated to be true.

What change would these two fields be true?

Comment: Are you sure of that? I just tried it and got 'true' on wasReplaced. I don't know what would set wasUpdated to 'true' though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own stupid mistake.  I copied the example from the Javadocs and added several else if blocks, e.g.

```
if(change.wasAdded()) {
  //doAdd
} else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
  //doRemove
} else if (change.wasReplaced()) {
  //doReplace
}
```

doReplace() was never getting called because it was an else if and not an if.  Thanks to @ftkg for the advice to get me here.